# Queue in Java not working

Tags: java, queue

```
class Que{
char q[];
int front , rear ;

Que(int size){
    q = new char[size];
    front = rear =0;
}
void push(char ch){
    if(rear == q.length){
        System.out.println("Que is Full");
    }
    else{
        q[rear++]=ch;
        System.out.println(ch + " Added");
    }
}
void pop(){
    if(front==rear){
        System.out.println("Que is Empty");

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(q[front] + " Is being popped ");
        front++;
    }
}
void disp(){

    char temp = q[front];
    for(int i = front;i<rear ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(q[i]);
    }

}


 }
 class Example{

public static void main(String args[])
throws java.io.IOException{

    Que Sample1 = new Que(10);
    int opt = 1;
    char j,k;
    while(opt!=0){
        System.out.println("1-Add , 2 - Pop , 3 - Display");
        j = (char) System.in.read();
        if(j=='1'){
            System.out.println("What to push ?");
            k = (char)System.in.read();
             Sample1.push(k);
        }
        else if(j=='2'){
            Sample1.pop();
        }
        else if(j=='3'){
            Sample1.disp();
        }
        else if(j=='4'){
            opt = 0;
        }
        else{ System.out.println("Try Again");}

    }
}
}
```

This is not working . When I compile and run it it show me the main menu and as soon as I press 1)ADD - it skips displaying 'Added' msg from the function .
What am I doing wrong?

When I press 1 (Add) it should ask me "what To Push " which it does, but then does not wait for my input and plays loop again .

So this is what displays --
1)ADD
2)Pop
3)Display
1
What to push ( takes no input)
Added (automatically displayed)
1)ADD
2)Pop
3)Display

Comment: Can you give the console output? It would help to troubleshoot.

Comment: I would vote to reopen this if I could.. this *is* a MCVE, and the desired behavior is not to skip displaying the 'Added' msg

Comment: Your Que class looks good at a glance. I was able to get your application working by getting rid of your `System.in` calls. I believe the issue you have here is problems with your input. I would suggest looking into the `Scanner` class, or revising your `System.in` calls.

Comment: DoubleDouble - is there something I could do to reopen it ? Sorry not very familiar . :)

Comment: Editing the question will move it to a queue where it can be reopened - which you already have done, just takes some time

Comment: The easiest way to figure out what is happening [is to step through it in your debugger](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html). This is an essential tool for programming. If you do that, you find that `System.in.read();` reads your `1` - but what was the next thing you pushed on the keyboard? *The enter key* - on the next `read` call it gets `\r` for "new line". and attempts to push it - displaying the `Added` msg after printing the new line. Then it loops back up to top - where it reads the next character, which is the `\n` from `println`, which displays `Try Again`

Comment: How can I make System.in.read() accept my input without pressing enter key ? @DoubleDouble

Comment: Your solution is to have a `Scanner` - set up a Scanner at the start with `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` - then instead of `j = (char) System.in.read();`, use `String result = scanner.nextLine(); j = result.charAt(0);` (*replace `k` as well*) You will still push `enter`, but it will read a line at a time, so it will keep up.

Comment: Thank You So Much :) @DoubleDouble

Answer (score 2):

What are you typing in your terminal ?

If you type more than one character for example `11` or even `1<Enter>`, your second call to `System.in.read()` will immediatly return with this second character: `1` or `<Enter>`.

Comment: Well I press 1 and then press enter key . Doesn't System.in.read() require enter to be pressed to accept the character input ?

Comment: @BonnyMahajan try running without pushing the enter key.

Comment: @Destruktor Can you please tell me how to get my input accepted without pressing Enter after 1